# Chrome extension architecture for real time update: websocket vs. regular fetch

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, architecture, websocket, socket.io

I'm building an app which is made of a webserver (currently using NodeJS but doesn't really matter here) and a Chrome extension.

The point of the Chrome extension is to display some data from the server. For this, I need the extension to be aware of changes on the server-side. To do that, I see 3 possible strategies :

#### 1. Websocket

Having a websocket in the background that triggers updates in real time.

#### 2. Regular fetch

But I also can have a timer that will fetch new data on a defined frequency (something like every minute)

#### 3. Event triggered fetch

Another solution would be to detect browser activity, and to trigger a server call during that activity (eg. on active tab changed)

---

The tradeof I see is browser memory/network usage vs. realtimeness.

To define realtimeness necessity, I'd compare it to an unread email indicator: it doesn't matter if the user is made aware a minute after, but conceptually, it means always displaying out-dated data, which doesn't sound great to me.

On the other hand, if using websockets, or event listeners come at a too high cost and will eventually slow down the browser too much, I'd rather have a minute delay. :)

But maybe fetching the server every minute with most of the time no update to send may be even more expensive than keeping a websocket alive...

Well, any insights on this tradeof and how to choose would be highly appreciated!

Special thanks to @Rob-w for helping me to reformulate the question.

Comment: What makes you think that #2 is cheaper than #1? And what is the kind of data that you're getting? Do you need to send data to the server as well, or is it read-only?

Comment: It'll only receive small amounts of text. I imagine #1 is more expensive because keeping a connection alive *should* require more round trips/cpu disponibility than opening one every minute or so. Shouldn't it? It is driven by intuition, I'm unclear on how websockets work behind the scene.

Comment: I asked three questions and you've just answered the first one. I understand your reasoning, but the conclusion might not be accurate depending on the answer to the other two questions that I asked.

Comment: > "It'll only receive small amounts of text." Sorry if that was not clear enough, but it does answer the two other questions: the kind of data is text, and no need to write on the server in return, since I can handle this with an ajax request from the extension afterwards.

Comment: By kind of data, I mean how important is the "realtimeness", how often does the data change. By "need to send data to the server", I meant to ask whether it is important that the server receives a request from a client, or if it is only necessary for the client to receive the data. And I assume that you have control over both the client and server, so you are free to choose the technologies (if not, please say so). And please put the answer to the questions that I asked in your question, because they form a crucial part of your question.

Comment: Thanks for coming back. I completely rewrote the question. You are right I was not clear that I'm actually writing the server code also.